# Install apks without sdcard and adb

Tags: android, apk, adb

My phone's sdcard reader and usb are  broken. How can I install apks? (no root)
I have tried airdroid,  dropbox, webhosting and more, but it dosen't work.

Comment: [Download this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) and download apk from cloud storage like as Google-Drive, DropBox ...etc

Comment: @CapDroid This person can't install apk files since his/her sdcard reader and usb are broken. so how he/she install [ES File Explorer File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) on his/her device ?

Comment: @Bishan I think there is PlayStore in device.

Comment: Please take care of your phone. And if you can access internet via your phone, use play store to install apps.

Comment: @CapDroid IF PlayStore in the device, this person shouldn't ask this question. If this person need to install apk files, which aren't in the google play, your method is correct. question is unclear.

Comment: @Bishan may be he want to install app for testing purporse.

Comment: @CapDroid Yes. that is why i told this question is unclear. if this person told his/her necessity correctly, we can give the exact answer for the question. :)

Comment: better to close this question...

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to [google play](https://play.google.com) and install apps.
2. Send email with apk attached to own address. Then open the email with email client on your android phone and tap on apk file.

Comment: Dosen't work... asks for sd card :(

Comment: @rebane2001 Android apps install to the internal storage by default, but if you set the SD card as your default install location, it asks for sd card.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options-
google play
outside google play(dropbox,email attachment etc) - **here remember to check "allow installation of app from unknown sources" in your settings.**

Comment: Dosen't work... asks for sd card :(